# Excel two-column range to single-column csv

Tags: excel, csv

I have a range of years in two columns:

[image]

And I want to convert it to a single column expanded by csv:

[image]

Is this possible via Excel formulas?  Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to CSE together textjoin, indirect and row but a UDF is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,A1:B1)
```

Drag it down to do the whole column.